# Limiting rows from Joined Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

If I run an inline select subquery, I can filter the rows to line up with the root query.  E.G.

```
A.Field1, A.Field2, (SELECT B.Field1 FROM tblB as B WHERE B.AID = A.ID ORDER BY B.DateAdded LIMIT 1)
FROM tblA as A
```

But If I try to move that select subquery to a joined subquery I can't use the where criteria (WHERE B.AID = A.ID) and there's no way to limit tblB fields to only matching tblA's row.

So what is the correct way to modify the query so I can select B.Field1, B.Field2, etc. when dealing with a 1:M?

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e566/1)**

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Also, explain what "not working" means.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried taking out the LIMIT 1 from the subquery ?

Comment: Does it return no rows at all, or just NULL values for PaidPrice and InitialQty? If the latter, and the subquery by itself *does* return data, then apparently there is no match between LastPurchase.RedinID and R.ID. Check those values to see if they are filled in and valid.

Comment: The LIMIT 1 in the subquery is only going to return the "most recent" tblTags. If there is more than one tblmateriallots row associated with it, the one used will be effectively random; meaning that even if it has a matching ResinID, that may not be the one chosen.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Uueerdo is correct, I setup a sql fiddle to illustrate the problem.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e566/1

I just don't know how to limit it to the most recent purchase/tag while still lining up with the resin from the main query.